# Gradle error: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Here's my gradle file. I am trying to add a zxing embedded dependency.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "it.jaschke.alexandria"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

jacoco {
    version = '0.6.2.201302030002'
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        testCoverageEnabled = true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug{
        testCoverageEnabled = true
    }

}
lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}
}
repositories {
jcenter()
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.0.2@aar'
compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by updating android sdk and then cleaning and rebuilding the project. Don't know what caused the error but it worked.